# Laravel Passport Does Not Authenticate User After Receiving Access Token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, bearer-token, laravel-10

I'm using Laravel 10 and Laravel Passport and in this project, I tried registering new users like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

        return response([
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }
```

Then I defined another route which is under `api` middleware:

```
Route::post('register',[AuthenticationController::class,'register']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
});
```

And in the ProductController I tried adding this method for storing new products:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|max:255',
            'price' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($request->user()) {
            Product::create([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'user_id' => $request->user()->id
            ]);

            return response([
                'message' => 'product created successfully'
            ],201);
        }else{
            return response(['message' => 'User not authenticated.'], 401);
        }
    }
```

But when I test the url in PostMAN which is this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products
```

I get this message:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

However I have copied and pasted the token retrieved from `/register` rendpoint as **Token** input of Authorization section:

[image]

I also set the Headers to `Accept` and `application/json` and sent these form-data as Body:

```
title:myproduct
description:The production desc
price:2000
```

I don't know why I get this Unauthenticated Message, I also configured the `auth.php` like this:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

And added this Service Provider to `app.php`:

```
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

And used the correct class at User Model:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    ...
}
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE #1**:

Result of `dd($user->createToken('MyApp'));`:

[image]

Comment: Can you help with what is the response of `$user->createToken('MyApp')`?

You can do like `dd($user->createToken('MyApp'))`

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham I put and Update #1 for you, plz check it out...

Comment: In postman, if you have already selected `Authorization` type as `Bearer Token` then no need to add `Bearer` before actual token in field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the token incorrectly in Postman when you select `Bearer Token` from the authorization tab as type. You don't have to add `Bearer` before your token in this case, that is why your token is getting mismatched. Check the below screenshot of how the string `Bearer` is getting prepended twicce to your access token.

[image]

---

Instead, you just need to add the `access token` to the value which should solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not retrieving your token correctly. You must provide this value to the user

> ```
>   $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken;
> ```

so you can do this

```
      $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken;

        return response([
            'token' => $token
        ]);
```

If you then use that $token string value as your BearerToken you should be fine.

As a good rule of thumb you should check that your plain text token starts with a number.

eg

> 29|NFAXFH5HRbZtdM1knfHTRXpB8VmVYkIlCELOB3ef0daf95da

The plain text token is not stored in your database